# Unable to find column with logical name: getting crazy :)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Maybe I am too much deep in the code and I am not able to look at it with perspicacity anymore. So could you please help me? :D

I know that there are already some posts with the same error but I tried several proposals and it does not solve my issue.

Here is the situation:

I have to manage historical records.

I have the following 3 tables:

```
|-------------------|
| HIST_CUSTOMERS    |
|-------------------|
| cust_id      PK   |
| cust_version PK   |
| ...               |
|-------------------|

Possible values:
100 | 1
100 | 2
101 | 1
100 | 3
...


|---------------------|
| HIST_COLLABORATORS  |
|---------------------|
| id               PK |   <- Sequence
| cust_id          FK |
| cust_version     FK |
| contact_id       FK |   <- FK to the Contact History table (HIS_CONTACTS)
| ...                 |
|---------------------|

Possible values:
200 | 100 | 1 | 400
201 | 100 | 1 | 401
202 | 100 | 1 | 402
203 | 100 | 2 | 400
203 | 100 | 2 | 401
204 | 100 | 2 | 402
205 | 100 | 2 | 403
206 | 101 | 1 | 402
...



|---------------------|
| HIST_CONTACTS       |
|---------------------|
| id               PK |   <- Sequence
| contact_id       FK |   <- FK to the real Contact table
| contact_version     |
| lastname            |
| firstname           |
| ...                 |
|---------------------|

Possible values:
300 | 400 | 1 | Dooe  | John
301 | 400 | 2 | Doe   | John
302 | 400 | 3 | Doe   | Bill
303 | 401 | 1 | McFly | Marthy
304 | 401 | 2 | McFly | Marty
305 | 402 | 1 | Nanny | Super
306 | 403 | 1 | Klaus | Santa
307 | 403 | 2 | Claus | Santa
...
```

Here are my entities:

HisCustomer:

```
/**
 * List of contacts
 */
// 1 <-> * 
@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<HisCollaborator> collaboratorList;
```

HisCollaborator:

```
/**
 * id
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="HIS_COLLAB_SEQ")    
@Column(name="ID")
private Integer id;

/**
 * Customer
 */
// * <-> 1
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID", referencedColumnName="CUST_ID",nullable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="CUST_VERSION", referencedColumnName="CUST_VERSION",nullable=false)
})
private HisCustomer customer;

/**
 * contact
 */
// * <-> * 
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
    name="HIS_COLLABORATORS",
    joinColumns={      @JoinColumn(name="CONTACT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CONTACT_ID", nullable=true)  },
    inverseJoinColumns={      @JoinColumn(name="CONTACT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CONTACT_ID", nullable=true)  }
)
private List<HisContact> contact;
```

HisContact:

```
/**
 * id
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="HIS_CONTACT_SEQ")    
@Column(name="ID")
private Integer id;

/**
 * collaborators
 */
// * <-> * 
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="contact", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<HisCollaborator> collaborators;
```

I get the following Hibernate error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with
>   logical name: CONTACT_ID in
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Table(HIS_COLLABORATORS) and its
>   related supertables and secondary tables  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:551)

If a set the relation between HIS_COLLABORATORS and HIS_CONTACTS as a One-to-One, I have no error but it does not fit my needs.
By the way, what I need is to have the entity HisCollaborator linked to the last version of HIST_CONTACTS (for a given CONTACT_ID) ; if you have a better solution, I am open)

Any idea?
I am really getting crazy!

Thanks,
Termos

Answer (score 0):

```
|---------------------|
| HIST_COLLABORATORS  |
|---------------------|
| id               PK |   <- Sequence
| cust_id          FK |
| cust_version     FK |
| id_contact       FK |   <- FK to the Contact History table (HIS_CONTACTS)
```

Here I read `id_contact` in the error it searches for `CONTACT_ID`. Which column do you expect it to use then?

Comment: I have edited my initial post. It is due to the fact that I have made some transformations to avoid to publish corporate code.